# Printing Int as float,double,long double and vice versa

Tags: c, floating-point, int

Trying to make a code have union structure.I am gonna scan integer and printf as int float,double,long double.Then scan float print as int,float,double,long double.And same procedure for double and long int.

1. Is this code should  working properly? It gives weird numbers when printing int as float.I not sure about results!

Code Below:

```
union Data
{
   int num_i;
   float num_f;
   double num_d;
   long double num_ld;
};


int main()
{
    union Data data;



   printf("Int girin");
   scanf("%d",&data.num_i);
   printf("Int %d\n",data.num_i);
   printf("Float %f\n",data.num_i);
   printf("Double %Lf\n",data.num_i);
   printf("Long DOuble %Ld\n",data.num_i);


   printf("Float gir");
   scanf("%f",&data.num_f);

   printf("Int %d\n",data.num_f);
   printf("Float %f\n",data.num_f);
   printf("Double %Lf\n",data.num_f);
   printf("Long DOuble %Ld\n",data.num_f);

   printf("Double Gİr");
   scanf("%lf",&data.num_d);

   printf("Int %d\n",data.num_d);
   printf("Float %f\n",data.num_d);
   printf("Double %lf\n",data.num_d);
   printf("Long DOuble %ld\n",data.num_d);

   printf("Long gir ");
   scanf("%ld",&data.num_ld);

   printf("Int %d\n",data.num_ld);
   printf("Float %f\n",data.num_ld);
   printf("Double %lf\n",data.num_ld);
   printf("Long DOuble %ld\n",data.num_ld);



   getch();
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: And your question is what?

Comment: Why isn't somebody asking what the question is here?

Comment: Forgot to ask. I edit.

Comment: Doing a `scanf("%d",&data.num_i);` likely does _not_ initialize all the bits of `data`.  Suggest first `memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));` before _each_ `scanf()`

Comment: "It gives weird numbers ", Suggest showing what you entered and what was printed.

Answer (score 2):

This code invokes undefined behavior. Using wrong conversion specification for a datatype invokes undefined behavior.

#### 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.282) If any argument is
> not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
> undefined.

In case of UB all bets are off.

Comment: Which specifier should i use?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Table-of-Input-Conversions.html

Comment: Is printing integer as float possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wanting to demonstrate the use of the union to print different types without casting so

```
printf("Int girin");
scanf("%d",&data.num_i);
printf("Int %d\n",data.num_i);
printf("Float %f\n",data.num_f);
printf("Double %Lf\n",data.num_d);
printf("Long DOuble %Ld\n",data.num_ld);
```

Comment: Yes but i want each variable in union should be printed as a integer numbers, a float, a double, and long 
double.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour to access any member of this union that wasn't the last one you set (regardless of whether you print it or not). The original code didn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, to print a number as another type of number, you should be typecasting it first or something along those lines. For example;

```
int a = 10;
double b = 5.5;
```

If I wanted to print them, respectively, as a `double` and as an `int`, then I should be doing the following:

```
// %f looks for a double
printf( "%f\n", (double) a );
printf( "%d\n", (int) b );

// output would be:
// 10.000000
// 5
```

About your `union`, I am not sure what you're expecting to have in your hands there, but you are overwriting the same memory location over and over again, with the each `scanf` call. elements inside `union`s share the same memory location, a memory location that is large enough to hold the largest element inside.

So, be careful about that. If you want to have all 4 by the end, you should consider using a `struct` instead of a `union`.

Comment: Is this correct?I changed the code like               printf("Float %f\n",(float)data.num_i);
printf("Double %Lf\n",(double)data.num_i);
printf("Long DOuble %Ld\n",(long double)data.num_i);

Comment: As I said, `"%f"` is actually for the type `double`, and there actually is no type-specifier for `float`, you just use `"%f"` for both `double` and `float`. `"%Ld"` is correct for `long double`. Other than that, all good.

Answer (score 0):

1) Match the field with the correct format specifier for both `scanf()` and `printf()`.  This also implies not all warnings were enabled.  Enable them.

2) Zero fill `data` as the `scanf()` of a union field may not completely set all bits in the union.

3) Added a hex dump.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>

union Data {
  int num_i;
  float num_f;
  double num_d;
  long double num_ld;
};

void uprintf(const union Data *data) {
  printf("Int         %d\n", data->num_i);
  printf("Float       %f\n", data->num_f);
  printf("Double      %lf\n", data->num_d);
  printf("Long Double %Lf\n", data->num_ld);  // was  %Ld and %ld
  unsigned char *x = (void *) data;
  printf("hex     ");
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(*data); i++)
    printf(" %02X", *x++);
  printf("\n");
}

int main() {
  union Data data;

  memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
  printf("Int girin");
  scanf("%d", &data.num_i);
  uprintf(&data);

  memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
  printf("Float gir");
  scanf("%f", &data.num_f);
  uprintf(&data);

  memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
  printf("Double Gİr");
  scanf("%lf", &data.num_d);
  uprintf(&data);

  memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
  printf("Long gir ");
  scanf("%Lf", &data.num_ld);  // was "%ld"
  uprintf(&data);

  //getch();
  return 0;
}
```